# My react apps no longer starts in 127.0.0.1:port_number, but works in only localhost:port_number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Initially my react apps used to start at `127.0.0.1:5173`, and it would work when I navigate to `localhost:5173` as well. After some time however, starting my react app works only on `localhost:port_number`, and when manually navigating to `127.0.0.1:port_number` I'm getting a "Can't reach page error".

I've tried to re-install the app, and also tested on a different browser but it still yielded the same results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.